# Additional line and extra array elements when writing multiple data types to file

Tags: c++

**I have discarded the project and started anew. Please disregard.**

New here. I've got an assignment, and I've been having trouble with the Editing part of my code. I'll post it below, but basically what the code does is add new items to a txt file, and later read from the file and allow the user to edit the numbers. I'm only trying to work on adding now, as subtracting can be dealt with later. The problem is, with each successive "Edit" of the file, which I read into an array, the file becomes more and more disorganised. First time, and extra blank line is added. A second time, Another extra blank line is added and information from another part of the file is copy and pasted partially.

I really appreciate any help in advance. I'll post the function below.

```
void BuyStock()     //Searches and Edits Customer Information

{
int i=0, j=0, n=0;
product item[1000];
int qty,q;
double cpi;
double price, p;


n=LineCount()-1;

i=ArrayAssign();
if (i>=n) cout << "No item found";

if (i>=n) return;

j=i;

ifstream FileSearch("stock.txt");
string name;

i=0;

if (FileSearch.is_open()){

while (!FileSearch.eof())
{
    getline(FileSearch, name, '|');
    item[i].name=name;
    FileSearch >> qty;
    item[i].qty=qty;
    getline(FileSearch, name, '+');
    FileSearch >> price;
    item[i].price=price;
    getline(FileSearch, name, '@');
    FileSearch >> cpi;
    item[i].cpi=cpi;
    i++;
}

}

else cout << "Error" << endl;

FileSearch.close();

cout << item[j].name << "     " << item[j].qty << "     " << item[j].price << "     " << item[j].cpi << endl;

cout << "Type in the changes, according to category. Retype if you want to keep the same data." << endl;    //Editing Section

cin.ignore();

cout << "Item name: " << item[j].name << endl;

cout << "Item quantity: ";
cin >> qty;
cin.ignore();
q = item[j].qty;
item[j].qty = q + qty;

cout << "Item price: ";
cin >> price;
cin.ignore();
p = item[j].price;
item[j].price = p + price;

item[j].cpi = item[j].price/item[j].qty;

ofstream FileSave("stock.txt");

for (j=0; j<n; j++){

    FileSave << item[j].name << " | " ;
    FileSave << item[j].qty << " + ";
    FileSave << item[j].price << " @ " ;
    FileSave << item[j].cpi;
    FileSave << endl;}

return;
```

}

EDIT: When trying print the array in cmd by using a for loop, I noticed that it's essentially repeating itself across 2 elements of the array, or repeating itself after leaving one array empty.

Comment: Hey, could you print out your n when editing the file? Your problem sounds to me like your n is somehow incorrectly read and then when your last for loop of writing runs, your j increases above the array bounds and accesses an item element that does not exist. I am not sure about that, which is why I didn't leave an answer. Playing around with the n might help. In general, try to get some outputs or use a debugger to see what is going on/going wrong.

Comment: Also, could you post some of the output of your program? That might help as well :) Thank you.

Comment: So, printing out the N when there's only 2 lines of info from the txt file shows, on the first run, 2, which is what I'm trying to. Getting the number of lines in the file. On the second run, it shows 3, which I suppose includes the extra empty line.

As for output, do you mean the txt file, or what comes out in cmd?

Thanks again!

Thinking about it, could it possibly be something wrong with my LineCount() function? @trashy

Comment: I am very curious about the command output, since I suspect there might be endline characters '\n' hiding in your name variable. That could happen since in all of your getline() you specify the character delimiter, but none of those are specified to be delimted by a newline character.

Oh, and could you also see what is in the file after you edited it with only 2 lines of text. Are there really 3 lines of text? And if so, where exactly is the newline entered?

Comment: Oh, I just had an idea:

In your for loop, remove the 
FileSave << endl;

and instead place
if(j!=n-1){FileSave<<endl;}

Comment: Same thing happens sadly :/ @trashy

Comment: Did you happen to print out the names yet? I still suspect there might be newlines hiding in there. I'll append my answer to explain what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Okay, decided to explain my last comment:

What I suspect to be perpetrator of the problem is follwing lines:

```
for (j=0; j<n; j++){

FileSave << item[j].name << " | " ;
FileSave << item[j].qty << " + ";
FileSave << item[j].price << " @ " ;
FileSave << item[j].cpi;
FileSave << endl;}
```

Let's see what these actually do on an actual document with just one single line in it. n=1, so the loop starts with j=0 and is run a single time.
We write all of our stuff into the first line, and then, to finish the loop off, we add a newline character, creating effectively 2 lines. The first with valid information, and the second with just the newline  character. This new line without information confuses our program on the subsequent tries.

So we can just end the loop by not putting a newline at the very last position, which would then look like:

```
for (j=0; j<n; j++){
    FileSave << item[j].name << " | " ;
    FileSave << item[j].qty << " + ";
    FileSave << item[j].price << " @ " ;
    FileSave << item[j].cpi;
    if(j!=n-1){FileSave << endl;}
}
```

Sadly, I could not test the code yet, but I do hope you can work with it :9

edit:: Okay, since that didn't work:

My second suspicion is that the name might start with a newline character since the newline character is never consumed. We might try to do something like:

```
while (!FileSearch.eof()){
    getline(FileSearch, name, '|');
    item[i].name=name;
    FileSearch >> qty;
    item[i].qty=qty;
    getline(FileSearch, name, '+');
    FileSearch >> price;
    item[i].price=price;
    getline(FileSearch, name, '@');
    FileSearch >> cpi;
    item[i].cpi=cpi;
    getline(FileSearch,name);
    i++;
}
```

Still not sure if that is the correct solution.

Any and all information about the state of the text document before and after each edit would really help :)

Comment: So, I tried doing that exact thing, but as I said before, the code just causes the same problem. I have a feeling it may have something to do with the fact I'm putting in different variable types. Some are string, some are int, some are double. Could that be it?

Comment: @Jass5991 The >> operator of an input stream usually deals with these types of things (see [operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) )
I would really love to know what is actually in the text file. Could you maybe write out what the contents are after each iteration, using just 1 or 2 lines at the beginning?

Comment: So, after two runs of adding new data to the text file (I've another function to do that) the file reads:

`Lenovo | 2 + 4 @ 2
Dell | 2 + 8 @ 4`

After the first "Edit" run the file reads:

`Lenovo  | 4 + 12 @ 3

Dell  | 2 + 8 @ 4`

Second "Edit" run leads to:

`Lenovo   | 6 + 24 @ 4


Dell   | 2 + 8 @ 4`

Third run:

`Lenovo    | 12 + 48 @ 4



Dell    | 2 + 8 @ 4
 | 0 + 0 @ 0`

This is by searching for "Lenovo". By searching for "Dell", 1st Edit:
`Lenovo   | 2 + 4 @ 2


Dell   | 4 + 16 @ 4`

And a 2nd run doesn't happen because it can't find "Dell". @trashy

Comment: @Jass5991

Sorry, I have to go now. Your problems definitely seems to be adding newlines where none should be. That can either happen in the string variable "name" or by writing too many endl directly through your writing loop.
The following problems then occur because n is too high after it reads how many lines there are in the document, since there are now additional empty lines.
Try to find out which of these two sources your additional new lines come from. That can be done by closely looking at how "name" is output, and by seeing how many endl the loop actually writes.